# How do I assign different dots different colors in a scatter plot made with MatPlotLib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using MatPlotLib and Python, I am making a scatter plot of laptops that has cost on the x-axis and rating on the y-axis. The data is now stored in a tab-separated file.

This link describes MatPlotLib scatter plots.
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/unicode_minus.html

Each laptop's brand is Lenova, HP, or Dell. I want to assign different colors for dots representing laptops of each brand. For instance, Dell laptops are marked by a blue point, while Lenova laptops are represented by a red point.

How can I do that?

Comment: Probably the best bet is to have the three groups, and call `scatter()` three times. [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) makes this easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better example for you would be the [scatter plot example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/scatter_demo2.html).

In your case, in place of the `close` array, you want some array of strings that are one of `'r'`, `'g'`, or `'b'`.  So if you can read an array of the brands, you can then translate that into an array of those characters.  (And I guess you don't want the equivalent of the `volume` array, which makes the circles different sizes.)

You could translate your `brand` array to colors with something like

```
brandcolors = [brand[i].replace('HP','g').replace('Lenovo','r').replace('Dell','b') for i in range(len(brand))]
```

Then, the plotting function would look like

```
scatter(cost, rating, c=brandcolors)
```

Adding a legend gets a little tricky.  The [matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist) suggest using a "proxy artist", where you create something, but don't put it on the plot.  For example:

```
pr = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc='r')
pg = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc='g')
pb = Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fc='b')
legend([pr, pg, pb], ['Lenovo', 'HP', 'Dell'])
```

That's a little ugly because it comes out as a rectangle regardless of the dot shape.  The other possible hack is to actually plot a single dot, but make sure it stays off the plot area.

```
plot([-100], 'ro', label='Lenovo')
...
ax.set_ylim(bottom=0)
legend()
```

Comment: Although... in this case, do you have any idea of how to add a legend? This manually replaces the brand names, so the legend cannot be automatically generated, right?

Comment: Edited an attempt at an answer.  The other option is to just do multiple calls to scatter, as in -- oh, let's say -- [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3AWeight_Growth_of_RN_First_Rate_Line-of-Battle_Ships_1630-1875.svg)