# Making a 2 color scatterplot with plot_date in Matplotlib

Tags: excel, matplotlib, plot, scatter

I'm making a basic scatterplot for a school project similar to the one here: [How do I assign different dots different colors in a scatter plot made with MatPlotLib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316664/how-do-i-assign-different-dots-different-colors-in-a-scatter-plot-made-with-matp)

The only difference is my data is movie revenues by release date. So x-axis is release dates, and y-axis is revenue. I have a third column that indicates if the movie is Chinese or Foreign, and I want to assign red and blue to the scatter points based on that. I used the method in the link to assign Chinese to 'r' and Foreign to 'b'.

However plot_date doesn't seem to to take the same c = colors argument. I get this error:

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
colors = [x2['Country and Region'].replace('Foreign','b').replace('China','r')]
mpl.pyplot.plot_date(x2['Release date'],x2['Total Box Office (million)'], c = colors)
fig.autofmt_xdate()

ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "[0     r
1     b
2     r
3     b
4     r
5     b
6     r
7     r
8     r
9     r
10    b
11    b
12    r
13    b
14    r
15    r
16    b
17    b
18    r
19    b
20    r
21    r
22    b
23    b
24    b
Name: Country and Region, dtype: object]"
length of rgba sequence should be either 3 or 4

How can I fix this? Is there another plot method I should be using? I am using plot_date because I couldn't get the plot to display with mpl.pyplot.scatter. (The dates are formatted mm/dd/yr and come from an excel sheet. When I try .scatter it says invalid type promotion. [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7lhX.png).[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QulMC.png))